# Getting different product id for different categories

Tags: url, search, magento-1.9, categories, product

I am trying to add a link on my website's product pages and redirect the users based on the category that the product belongs to. For example, I have a category **chairs** which is having a **Category Id of 39** and I am having another category **desks** for which the **category id is 52**.

Now my issue with the above scenario is when I am moving into the product page through category pages I am getting the above-mentioned category Id's properly and the URL will be

```
http://example.com/chairs/wood-chair.html
```

but when I am trying to search for the product directly from the search box and move into the product page from there the URL becomes

```
http://example.com/wood-chair.html
```

the **category id becomes 2** and this happens with every category and it shows the category name as default category when I go to the product page through search box. How can I resolve this? kindly let me know if there is any parameter that doesn't change on the product page which can enable me to display the content based on the category the product belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You can force magento to set a category with adding an observer on `catalog_controller_product_view`:

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function addCategoryToBreadcrumbs(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            return;
        }

        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(false);
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

        if (count($categoryIds)) {
            $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);

            $categories->getSelect()->order('level DESC')->limit(1);

            Mage::register('current_category', $categories->getFirstItem());
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>Full code here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178268/add-category-path-to-breadcrumbs-on-product-view-page/178592#178592</sup>